# EF6 DB first View Generation T4 Template for C#

Tags: entity-framework, code-generation, t4, codegen

I am currently in the process of updating EF5 to Ef6. We are using database first approach. in EF5 i have T4 template that generates mapping views for EF5. But for EF6 that template would not work. 
In VS 2013 -> Add new Item shows there is a template available online for "EF6 Codefirst View Generation T4 Template for C#", however im using DB first, is there any template available to create mapping views for C#? ( Note that EF power tool can create  mapping views, however i would like to use T4 to generate it)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still necessary with EF6's improved view generation out of the box.

Comment: View generation can still be very useful for large projects. Unfortunately, I've not found a better solution for this either.